# method pointer/ref in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is an example of my current code :

```
var myObject = new Obj();

if(something)
    myObject.method1(arg1, arg2);
else
    myObject.method2(arg1, arg2);
```

and how I declared my obj :

```
function Obj() { }

Obj.prototype.method1 = function(a, b) { }
Obj.prototype.method2 = function(a, b) { }
```

Since i'm doing this kind of test a bunch of time, I was wondering if it was possible to do something like that :

```
if(something)
    var method = method1;
else
    var method = method2;

myObject.method(arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, so you can store function references in variables and then call the function via the variable. In your case, you need to do that in a special way to ensure that `this` is `myObject` within the call:

```
var method;
if(something)
    method = myObject.method1;
else
    method = myObject.method2;

method.call(myObject, arg1, arg2);
```

Note the use of `call` there at the end: That allows you to call a function and control what `this` is within the function call.

If the condition really is that short, you can do this:

```
var method = something ? myObject.method1 : myObject.method2;
method.call(myObject, arg1, arg2);
```

Or even:

```
var method = something ? "method1" : "method2";
myObject[method](arg1, arg2);
```

More to explore:

- `Function#call` ([in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) | [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call))
- `Function#apply` ([in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) | [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply))
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) *(on my blog)*
- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) *(on my blog)*

Comment: just for curiosity, why did you write `method = myObject.method1`, it seems a bit redundant since myObject is already mentioned in call(). Wouldn't `method = Obj.prototype.method1` make more sense ? But thanks, that's exactly what I wanted ^^

Comment: @user1278743: I seem to have missed that question. We may not know that `myObject` doesn't have a special `method1`. If it doesn't, then `myObject.method1` and `Obj.prototype.method1` refer to the same function and the latter is just more typing, but if it *does*, we'd get the wrong method. :-) It also might not be clear to people reading the code that `myObject` is backed by `Obj.prototype` so clarity would suffer.

Answer (score 1):

You use a function reference in a variable like this:-

```
var method;
if(something)
    var method = myObject.method1;
else
    var method = myObject.method2;

method.call(myObject, arg1, arg2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just do:

```
var method = myObject.method1;
```

then call it like:

```
method.call(myObject);
```

but you can also `bind` method to an object:

```
var method = myObject.method1.bind(myObject);
```

then you can call it normally:

```
method();
```

and `this` inside will be `myObject`

you can replace `bind` with simple:

```
var method = function() { myObject.method1(); }
```

if you want to support older browsers